# getting undefined import of postgres in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

I have an application that uses `pg` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)
and it does so without issues, however now that I started writing tests for it with jest, I am getting issues importing `pg`.

this is what jest says when I run the test

```
    TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Client' of '_pg.default' as it is undefined.

      1 | import pg from "pg";
      2 | console.log("pg:" + pg);
    > 3 | const { Client } = pg;
```

and the console output agrees with it being undefined.

The weird part is that it is no issue when the application uses it.

so not sure if it is related to jests babel config?

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
  plugins: [
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: false }],
  ],
};
```

might be a missmatch between it and tsconfig?

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

I tried removing babel and installed `ts-jest` instead with this config

```
//jest.config.js
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.json",
    },
  },
};
```

and I get the exact same error, so probably not babel related, but I can't figure out how/why there is a diff between test and "non-test".

and I am doing the same thing as the documentation for `pg` (as far as I can tell)

https://node-postgres.com/

Here are my test file and pg file.
I removed everything past where it fails (in order to not post too many lines).

```
//word/word.test.ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import { defineFeature, loadFeature } from "jest-cucumber";
import * as pg from "../pg";
...
```

```
//pg.ts
// import pg from "pg";
// console.log("pg:" + pg);
// const { Client } = pg;
// import { Client } from "pg";
const { Client } = require("pg");
console.log(Client);
if (!Client) process.exit(1);
// import pkg from "pg";
// const Client = pkg.Client;
```

```
//new error:
> jest --forceExit

  console.log
    undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pg.ts:6:9)

  ●  process.exit called with "1"

       5 | const { Client } = require("pg");
       6 | console.log(Client);
    >  7 | if (!Client) process.exit(1);
         |                      ^
       8 | // import pkg from "pg";
       9 | // const Client = pkg.Client;
      10 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pg.ts:7:22)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/word/word.test.ts:3:1)
```

the pg file is a mess with different ways of importing `pg` and no combination seems to have worked for me

Comment: Can you add your `.spec.ts` file to the message ? And if possible the file importing `pg` ? That may be useful to see the problem

Comment: I'm getting a similar error (although not using TS and error is with `@google-cloud/logging-winston` import), did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error with `@google-cloud/logging-winston` (and not using TS):

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'LoggingWinston' of '_loggingWinston.default' as it is undefined.`

I couldn't quite figure out why the library import was undefined because as you mentioned when running the code it executed fine.

Instead, as a work around, I [manually mocked](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks) the module and it solved it for me.

Hope it helps someone.

**[EDIT] 09/01/23**

So as I expanded my test coverage I kept running into this issue with other imports and obviously just mocking every module like above is totally impractical. So after some more digging it turns out the issue was rooted in the fact that these modules don't have default exports, an easy fix was to update the import statement:

From:

```
import dateFns from 'date-fns'
const { format } = dateFns
```

To:

```
import * as dateFns from 'date-fns'
const { format } = dateFns
```

Comment: Why is testing on the frontend so goddamn miserable?